# Font rendering differences on Puppeteer in local Docker vs CircleCI Docker

Tags: docker, puppeteer, circleci, storybook

I'm running a visual snapshots test suite (with Storybook), I run it locally inside a Docker container to generate the snapshots and update them, and then I run it on CircleCI to check the stored snapshots match the ones generated by the updated code.

This is my local `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  visual:
    image: buildkite/puppeteer
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    command: yarn test:visual:ci
```

And this is my CircleCI config:

```
  frontend-tests:
    docker:
      - image: buildkite/puppeteer
        environment:
          WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT: '45'
    working_directory: ~/repo/frontend
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/repo

      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - run:
          name: visual regression tests
          command: yarn test:visual:ci
```

For some reason, the font rendering is different on my local Docker container compared to the CircleCI docker container...

The base image is the same (`buildkite/puppeteer`) and I made sure they are both using the `latest` tag.

What could possibly lead two seemingly identical Docker images to differently render fonts inside Puppeteer?

Comment: Different font-family or different font options like anti-aliasing?

Comment: The test runner is the same. I use the same exact command

Comment: I know but you said the font rendering is different. _How different_? You got some screenshots?

Comment: Did find a solution?